# VBA code bogging down computer during execution

Tags: vba, performance, excel, parallel-processing

The code below was designed to run through sheets in a workbook and carry out calculations based on headers found.  The issue that I am having is that the workbook contains sometimes up to 50 sheets of data with (at times) 2000 lines.  This bogs the computer down during execution of the code.

Is there a way to optimize this code so that the computer would not be bogged down or am I limited by using VBA for this process?  Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReturnMarginal()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLowLimCol As Long, strLowLimCol As String
    Dim lngHiLimCol As Long, strHiLimCol As String
    Dim lngMeasCol As Long, strMeasCol As String
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

    ' get worksheetfunction references
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    ' iterate worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        ' validate LowLimit label is on sheet
        If Not (ws.Rows(1).Find("LowLimit") Is Nothing) Then

        ' get location of input data columns and number of rows
        lngLowLimCol = wsf.Match("LowLimit", ws.Rows(1), 0)
        lngHiLimCol = wsf.Match("HighLimit", ws.Rows(1), 0)
        lngMeasCol = wsf.Match("MeasValue", ws.Rows(1), 0)
        lngLastRow = ws.Cells(1, lngLowLimCol).End(xlDown).Row

        ' get column letters for input data columns
        strLowLimCol = Split(ws.Cells(1, lngLowLimCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        strHiLimCol = Split(ws.Cells(1, lngHiLimCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
        strMeasCol = Split(ws.Cells(1, lngMeasCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

        ' output headers
        ws.Range("P1") = "Meas-LO"
        ws.Range("Q1") = "Meas-Hi"
        ws.Range("R1") = "Min Value"
        ws.Range("S1") = "Marginal"

        ' assign formulas to outputs
        ' Meas-LO
        'Range("P2:P" & lngLastRow).Select
        '    With Selection
        '        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        '        .Value = .Value
        '    End With
        With ws.Range("P2:P" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(" & strLowLimCol & "2" = ""---"," & 
                strMeasCol & "2-" & strLowLimCol & "2," & _
                9999)"

        End With

        ' Meas-Hi
        With ws.Range("Q2:Q" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(" & strHiLimCol & "2)," & _
                strMeasCol & "2-" & strHiLimCol & "2," & _
                9999 & "2)"
                'strMeasCol & "2)"
        End With

        ' Min Value
        With ws.Range("R2:R" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=MIN(P2,Q2)"
        End With

        ' Marginal
        With ws.Range("S2:S" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(AND(R2>=-3,R2<=3),""Marginal"",R2)"
        End With
        End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You could also read each sheets data into an array then process and then output back to the sheet. Sheet calls are expensive in terms of Running/ CPU time.

Comment: See also [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/doevents-function)

Comment: @TSion.D.P, I tried to implement that suggestion by putting it before the code that I have but I get the compile error `Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property`.  How do I incorporate that code into my existing code to see if helps with the timing?  Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest adding the DoEvents above each labour-intensive command.  So perhaps on the line before each with statement.

Comment: @A.S.H can you start me off on using the DoEvents.  I looked at the link you sent me, but I think I implemented it wrongly.

Comment: @Joe it is pretty simple. Insert a `DoEvents` statement anywhere you think you have spent much time calculating and it's not over. A good start is to inset it before and after each loop, and/or after finishing with each worksheet. It has no effect on the outcome of your calculation, just will slow it down a bit in favor of keeping the system stable and responding.

Comment: @A.S.H Will it be of this form:  `' Meas-LO
        For I = 1 To lngLastRow
        With ws.Range("P2:P" & lngLastRow)
            .Formula = "=IF(" & strLowLimCol & "2 = ""---"", 9999, " & _
            strMeasCol & "2-" & strLowLimCol & "2)"
            OpenForms = DoEvents
        End With
        Next I`?

Comment: No assignment, just `DoEvents` on a line by itself.